# Sequelize: Includes not working on defaultScope when querying an object through belongsToMany association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to move an include object to the default scope of my model `CommodityContract`. However, when I do this, sequelize throws me an error upon querying results:

`'Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.'`

Here is my block of code, which works perfectly if I put it inside a custom scope.

```
defaultScope: {
      include: [
        {
          model: sequelize.models.CommodityContractPayments,
          required: false
        },
        {
          model: sequelize.models.CommodityContractTreatmentCharges,
          required: false
        },
        {
          model: sequelize.models.CommodityContractRefiningCharges,
          required: false
        },
        {
          model: sequelize.models.CommodityContractPriceParticipation,
          required: false
        },
      ]
    }
```

The problem is that I am trying to query this specific model as a through object in a belongs-to-many association, and therefore I'm not sure how to apply a scope when querying, unless I do another separate query, which I was trying to avoid.

The main query looks like this:

```
const contract = await Contract.findOne(
        {
          where: { id },
          include: [
            sequelize.models.Commodity,
            sequelize.models.ContractSubstance,
            sequelize.models.Client,
            sequelize.models.Invoice.scope('default_includes')
          ]
        })
```

Where `Commodity` is linked to `Contract` through `CommodityContract`:

```
Commodity.belongsToMany(models.Contract, {
        through: models.CommodityContract,
        foreignKey: 'commodity_id',
        otherKey: 'contract_id'
      })
```

And the scope 'default_includes' is defined as such, within the model `Invoice`:

```
scopes: {
      default_includes: () => {
        return {
          include: [
            {
              model: sequelize.models.InvoiceVersion,
              required: false
            },
            {
              model: sequelize.models.Contract,
              required: false,
            },
            {
              model: sequelize.models.User,
              required: false,
            },
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I have had this problem quite a few times before and it annoys me greatly. Sometimes the includes work in a defaultScope, but sometimes it doesn't. Something tells me this has to do with the many-to-many association, but I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: in post, could you clarify which model's `defaultScope` that you are showing in the first block?  and also could you show where you define `default_includes` for `Invoice`?

Comment: Absolutely! Please check the post again :-)

Comment: Thanks.  It looks complex and I do not see where the error is from yet.  I would suggest to narrow down the problem by commenting out models other than 1 model in `include` and run one by one and see which model in `include` that giving you the error.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip. I'll try it out and report my findings

Comment: Any update to this? I'm having a similar issue.